# How to create blueprint for needle-client-react in Jhipster?

Tags: jhipster

I'm using [generator-jhipster](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster) and I want to create blueprints for entity-client. After writing entity files, a postWriting function will call `addEnitiyToMenu` in `generator-jhipster/generators/client/needle-api/needle-client-react.js` to add new entity generated to file `menu/entities.tsx`

I need to override this function to write a different `entityEntry` with original one.

But I can't find the template for it. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I can write these function by my own. There is example code if you need

```js
function generateFileModel(aFile, needleTag, ...content) {
    return {
        file: aFile,
        needle: needleTag,
        splicable: content,
    };
}

function addBlockContentToFile(rewriteFileModel, generator) {
    try {
        return jhipsterUtils.rewriteFile(rewriteFileModel, generator);
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        return null;
    }
}

function addToMenu() {
    if (this.skipClient) return;

    if (!this.embedded) {
        this.addEntityToModule();

        const entityMenuPath = `${this.CLIENT_MAIN_SRC_DIR}app/shared/layout/menus/entities.tsx`;
        const entityEntry =
            // prettier-ignore
            this.stripMargin(`|<Menu.Item key="${this.entityStateName}" icon={<FileOutlined />}>
                            | <Link to="/${this.entityStateName}">
                            |      ${this.enableTranslation ? `<Translate contentKey="global.menu.entities.${this.entityTranslationKeyMenu}" />` : `${_.startCase(this.entityStateName)}`}
                            | </Link>
                            |    </Menu.Item>`);
        const rewriteFileModel = generateFileModel(entityMenuPath, 'jhipster-needle-add-entity-to-menu', entityEntry);

        addBlockContentToFile(rewriteFileModel, this);
    }
}

function replaceTranslations() {
    if (this.clientFramework === VUE && !this.enableTranslation) {
        if (!this.readOnly) {
            utils.vueReplaceTranslation(this, [
                `app/entities/${this.entityFolderName}/${this.entityFileName}.vue`,
                `app/entities/${this.entityFolderName}/${this.entityFileName}-update.vue`,
                `app/entities/${this.entityFolderName}/${this.entityFileName}-details.vue`,
            ]);
        } else {
            utils.vueReplaceTranslation(this, [
                `app/entities/${this.entityFolderName}/${this.entityFileName}.vue`,
                `app/entities/${this.entityFolderName}/${this.entityFileName}-details.vue`,
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```